# DatagramChannel.close() keeps port open on Windows

Tags: java, udp, nio

I'm implementing a Discover process that:

- Open a UDP socket to listen for broadcast response on a given port
- Send some requests (and expect later response)
- Close the UDP socket after a given period of time

The first call works. But other call get a bind error. Address already in use: bind

I'm running Windows 7.  I did some tests and found that after a channel.close(); Netstat still gives:

netstat -a -b -sp udp | grep 55224

UDP    0.0.0.0:55224          *:*

So the udp port is still opened at the OS level

I searched the web and it may be a leak at the os level : [Some java Datagram Socket questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361741/some-java-datagram-socket-questions)

I ran 2 tests one using NIO channel and one without (from a test found on the web).  I reproduce my error with the NIO version but it works if I don`t use NIO.

I anybody can point me how I can make it works with NIO.  The targetted platform is Android where I don`t wan`t to always listen for broadcast but only for repetitive period of time.

### TEST SOCKET

```
    public void testConnectCloseWithSocket() {
    long tCumulative = 0;
    int errAt = -1;
    System.out.println("start...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        try {
            errAt = i;
            DatagramSocket result = new DatagramSocket(null);
            result.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9005));
            result.close();

            //success at last
            tCumulative = 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error (at="+errAt+") (waited="+tCumulative+"ms): " + e.getMessage());

            tCumulative+=50;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {


            }
            i--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("end...");

}
```

---

### RESULT SOCKET<

start...
Error (at=1319) (waited=0ms): Address already in use: Cannot bind

Error (at=1438) (waited=0ms): Address already in use: Cannot bind

Error (at=1587) (waited=0ms): Address already in use: Cannot bind

Error (at=1740) (waited=0ms): Address already in use: Cannot bind

end...

---

I did get some errors but the socket get closed properly... which is oki for my needs

### TEST WITH CHANNEL

```
    public void testConnectCloseWithChannel() {
    long tCumulative = 0;
    int errAt = -1;
    System.out.println("start...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        try {
            errAt = i;
            Selector selector = Selector.open();
            DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
            channel.configureBlocking(true);
            channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9005));
            SelectionKey clientKey = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            clientKey.cancel();
            channel.close();

            //success at last
            tCumulative = 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error (at="+errAt+") (waited="+tCumulative+"ms): " + e.getMessage());

            tCumulative+=50;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(tCumulative);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {


            }
            i--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("end...");

}
```

NOTE: It the channel.register is commented the test works ..

---

### RESULT WITH CHANNEL

start...
Error (at=0) (waited=0ms): null
Error (at=0) (waited=50ms): Address already in use: bind

Error (at=0) (waited=100ms): Address already in use: bind

Error (at=0) (waited=150ms): Address already in use: bind
...

---

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

> I did get some errors but the socket get closed properly... which is
>   oki for my needs

No, in case you've got errors your channel is NOT closed properly.

You have to do `close` in the `finally` clause of your `try` block.

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();
try
{
  DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();

  try
  {
    channel.configureBlocking(true);
    channel.socket().bind(
      new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 9005)
    );
    SelectionKey clientKey = channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    clientKey.cancel();
  }
  finally
  {
    channel.close();
  }
}
finally
{
  selector.close( )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Note and While working on your code I notice that I wasn't closing the selector.  By closing it everything works :-) Thanks!

Comment: @DavidGagnon That's because of the issue raised in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of a channel close are deferred to the next select() if the channel is registered with a Selector. It is documented somewhere in the forest of Selector, AbstractSelector, SelectorSpi, SelectableChannel, AbstractSelectableChannel, where I can never find it when I need it. If you're within the select loop and thread when you close the channel, you can make it immediate by calling selectNow().