# Why does Java DatagramSocket return false on "isConnected" when it is definitely connected?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, port, datagram

I am following the simple UDP tutorial [HERE](http://www.javatpoint.com/DatagramSocket-and-DatagramPacket), but I am running into an issue.

```
//DSender.java  
import java.net.*;  
public class DSender{  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    try{
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();  
        String str = "Welcome java";  
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");  

        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(), str.length(), ip, 3000);  
        ds.send(dp);  
        System.out.println(ds.isConnected());
    } catch(Exception e){
    } finally {
        ds.close();  
    }
  }  
} 


//DReceiver.java  
import java.net.*;  
public class DReceiver{  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    try{
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(3000);  
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];  
        DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, 1024);  
        ds.receive(dp);  
        String str = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());  
        System.out.println(str);  
    } catch(Exception e){
    } finally {
        ds.close();  
    }
  }  
}
```

Before I close the socket, I perform a:

```
ds.send(dp);
System.out.println(ds.isConnected());
ds.close();
```

on the connection, and it **always** comes back false, even though it is definitely connected, and has successfully sent a message from the client to the server. Reading the Java 7 API, it says:

> If the socket was connected prior to being closed, then this method will continue to return true after the socket is closed.

Since I called the isConnected() method before closing, it should read true. As an FYI, I have also used the getPort() method, and it always returns "-1", also indicating that it is not connected, even though it is.

> If the socket was connected prior to being closed, then this method will continue to return the connected port number after the socket is closed.

What is going on?

**EDIT:**  I posted the complete code from the page I linked to.

Comment: Well, have you called connect() on that socket ?

Comment: I see two DatagramSocket's in your code, `ds` nad `datagramSocket`! I doubt you have something different going on. Also, post the relevant code, OR better the code with which you're experimenting, this much is insufficient to answer the question.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Only one socket, I corrected my data entry mistake. Also, I posted a link to the exact code I am using.

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol and Java's interpretation of "connected" is super weird: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362448/995891

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Complete code posted.

Comment: @zapl According to the Java 7 API, the "isConnected()" method should work.

Comment: Read carefully, it's not saying that. You can connect a socket when you explicitly call `connect`, if you don't do that you can still send but in "not connected" mode. Connected mode means: *"When a socket is connected to a remote address, packets may only be sent to or received from that address. By default a datagram socket is not connected."* - meaning it is an optional security filter feature. You can limit the socket if you like.

Comment: @zapl So, I am trying to talk to a UDP server on a remote server somewhere. Is there a way, from my end, to check to see whether or not it is even connecting? I ask because I am having issues connecting.

Comment: You can not see if the data you send arrives unless you tell the other side manually to acknowledge packets as part of your protocol over UDP. UDP is designed that way. It's unreliable, but has the big advantage that you don't need to establish connections prior to sending data. You just push packets out and hope they arrive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the output of isConnected() true, you need to connect the DatagramSocket first to a particular InetAddress, and a port number, using the method `public void connect(InetAddress host, int port)`.

If you're not connecting it to a particular InetAddress and port, the result of isConnected() will be false. You could test than on your code.

From [Managing Connections topic in Chapter 12. UDP, of ***Java Network Programming Fourth Edition***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449357679) :-

> The connect() method doesn’t really establish a connection in the TCP
>   sense. However, it does specify that the DatagramSocket will only send
>   packets to and receive packets from the specified remote host on the
>   specified remote port. Attempts to send packets to a different host or
>   port will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. Packets received from a
>   different host or a different port will be discarded without an
>   exception or other notification.
>
> A security check is made when the connect() method is invoked. If the
>   VM is allowed to send data to that host and port, the check passes
>   silently. If not, a `SecurityException` is thrown. However, once the
>   connection has been made, send() and receive() on that DatagramSocket
>   no longer make the security checks they’d normally make.

Similarly, about

```
public int getPort()
```

> If and only if a DatagramSocket is connected, the getPort() method
>   returns the remote port to which it is connected. Otherwise, it
>   returns –1.

and about

```
public void disconnect()
```

> The disconnect() method breaks the “connection” of a connected
>   DatagramSocket so that it can once again send packets to and receive
>   packets from any host and port.